# Jsoup query multiple child selector

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to select child elements that descend directly from parent but I want to use multiple selector. I've tried the follwoing

```
"> p, >h3"
```

But It throws `SelectorParseException`

HTML sample code(I'm trying to get the first `<h3>` tag and the two `<p>` tags that follows):

```
<div class="content">
<h3 class="crossheading">Anschlag erinnert an Attentat in
    Westgate-Shopping-Mall</h3>
<p>Im Lauf des viert&auml;gigen Dramas starben mehr als 70
    Menschen, darunter die f&uuml;nf Attent&auml;ter; rund 175 weitere
    Personen wurden verletzt. Teile der Mall st&uuml;rzten in Folge der
    Kampfhandlungen ein.</p>
<p>Seit ihrer Vertreibung aus der somalischen Hauptstadt Mogadischu
    2011 ver&uuml;bte die Terrorgruppe al-Shabaab vermehrt Anschl&auml;ge
    im benachbarten Kenia und Uganda.</p>
<div class="infoEl center edge">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <header>
            <h2>Dschihadistische Terrorgruppen weltweit</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="hentry  landscape t9l  item1">
            <a
                href="/bild-plus/politik/ausland/isis/die-weltkarte-des-terrors-37906706.bild.html"
                class="variant"
                data-variation="{\u0022name\u0022:\u0022Conversion-AB-060115\u0022,\u0022variations\u0022:[{\u0022url\u0022:\u0022/bild-plus/politik/ausland/isis/die-weltkarte-des-terrors-37906706,var\u003da.bild.html\u0022,\u0022prop\u0022:50},{\u0022url\u0022:\u0022/bild-plus/politik/ausland/isis/die-weltkarte-des-terrors-37906706,var\u003db.bild.html\u0022,\u0022prop\u0022:50}]}"
                rel="bookmark"><img class="photo"
                src="http://bilder.bild.de/fotos-skaliert/teaser_40330727_mbqf-1418219891-38921172/2,w=189,c=0.bild.jpg"
                alt="K&auml;mpfer der Terrorgruppe „Islamischer Staat im Irak und in Syrien“" />
                <ul>
                    <li class="premium bildplus hide-text">Premium BildPlus
                        Inhalt</li>
                </ul>
                <h3 class="entry-title">
                    <span class="kicker">ISIS, al-Qaida, Taliban</span> <span
                        class="headline"><span>Der gro&szlig;e Terror-Check</span></span>
                </h3> </a>
            <p class="entry-content">
                ISIS ist auf den Vormarsch und damit nicht allein! BILD listet auf,
                welche Dschihad-Gruppen es gibt und wo sie agieren.<span> <a
                    href="/bild-plus/politik/ausland/isis/die-weltkarte-des-terrors-37906706.bild.html"
                    class="variant"
                    data-variation="{\u0022name\u0022:\u0022Conversion-AB-060115\u0022,\u0022variations\u0022:[{\u0022url\u0022:\u0022/bild-plus/politik/ausland/isis/die-weltkarte-des-terrors-37906706,var\u003da.bild.html\u0022,\u0022prop\u0022:50},{\u0022url\u0022:\u0022/bild-plus/politik/ausland/isis/die-weltkarte-des-terrors-37906706,var\u003db.bild.html\u0022,\u0022prop\u0022:50}]}"
                    rel="tag">mehr...</a></span>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

NOT: `".content > h3, .content > p"` won't help because I'm trying to build a generic web scraper.

Comment: Post the html please

Comment: You can use `div.content` to select the div with class `content`. Then it's just a matter of getting the first three children.

Comment: As I said I'm working on building a generic web scraper. This is not about specific HTML code. What I need is selecting child elements that descend directly from parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (desiredTag != null) {
        for (Element el : desiredTag.select("> *")) {
            if (!el.tagName().equals("p") && !el.tagName().equals("h3")
                    && !el.tagName().equals("h2")
                    && !el.tagName().equals("h1")) {
                el.remove();
            }
        }
        content = desiredTag.text();
    }
```

Here `desiredTag` is `<div>` tag which has `content` class

Comment: Isnt that achieved just by the query - "div.content"?

Comment: No. This code will remove `<div class="infoEl center edge">` tag which has `<p>` and `<h3>` tags inside.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a CSS Selector query:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("url").get();
//get h3
Element e1 = document.select("div.content > h3").first();
System.out.println(e1.text());

//get first p ..first() used as you are looking only for the first element
Element e2 = document.select("div.content > h3 + p").first();
System.out.println(e2.text());

//get second p
Element e3 = document.select("div.content > h3 + p:nth-child(2)").first();
System.out.println(e3.text());
```

I hope this helps!

You can try out the selector queries online on this site - http://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: I think that I couldn't explain my problem. Anyway I solved it by removing the unwanted tag from the child elements that descend directly from parent. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please post your answer and accept it! I'd like to see please